# RSA crypto when p==q

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, ctf

I participated in DawgCTF 2 days ago.
And I was about to solve RSA problem but I couldn't solve.

DawgCTF's RSA problem was given n, e, c.

so, I factorized n using factordb, and the result of n was the square of only one prime.(That is, n=p^2)

I've never seen a case where p and q are the same in RSA Crypto.
Anyway, I let phi be (p-1)(q-1) and wrote the code as below. (phi means Euler's phi)

```
from Crypto.Util.number import inverse, long_to_bytes
import string

n = ~~~ 
e = 65537
c = ~~~
p = ~~~ # I omit q because p==q


phi = (p-1) * (p-1)
d = inverse(e, phi)
m = pow(c, d, n)

m = long_to_bytes(m)
print(m)
```

But, it didn't work!!!

After CTF, I looked for a write-up, in which he did not put phi as (p-1)^2, but p*(p-1).
But, I don't know why...
Why phi should be p*(p-1) when p==q??

I'd really appreciate it if you could explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first equal sign in `phi(p * q) = phi(p) * phi(q) = (p - 1) * (q - 1)` assumes that `p` and `q` are coprime (see [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Phi_is_a_multiplicative_function)), while the second equal sign assumes that `p` and `q` are prime (see [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Value_of_phi_for_a_prime_power_argument), `k = 1`). `p = q` violates the first condition, which is why this relation is *not* valid for `p = q`.

On the other hand, for `k = 2`, it follows from [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Value_of_phi_for_a_prime_power_argument) `phi(p * p) = p * (p - 1)`, i.e. the relation used in the CTF solution for `p = q`.

For RSA in practice, however, `p != q` is a prerequisite, see [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation) and [[4]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26864) (otherwise `p` and `q` could be determined quickly: `p = q = sqrt(N)`).